# Handling a event in different instances of a class separately using an indexed singleton

Tags: c#, .net, events, singleton, sapb1

I'm working with the following singleton classes: `FormA`, `FormB` and `ShareFormDataEvent`.

---

- When I click in a button on `FormA`, a instance of `FormB` is created.
- On the `InitializeMethod` of `FormB`, I subscribe to a `ShareDataEvent` that is declared in `ShareFormDataEvent`.
- Then I Use `FormB.UniqueId` as key and store the `ShareDataEvent`(with the info of the EventHandler attached to it) in a dictionary in `ShareFormDataEvent` class.
- When `FormB` is created, **the next step is in *FormA***. I use `FormB.UniqueId` to access the dictionary in `EventHelper` to get the Event that is attached to the Handler of *FormB* and Invoke it.

---

This work fine, but when I create a new instance of a `FormB` by clicking again on the button in `FormA`, 
 and storing the event(with the handler) in the dictionary of `ShareFormDataEvent` and then, invoking the event for the second instance of `FormB`, the second instance handle the event two times.

I know that this happens because I'm storing the same instance of the event for the two instances of `FormB`. My idea at first was to use the `UniqueId` of the `FormB` to filter the "handling" of the event for the specific instance. But I'm not getting it.

I'll share with you some code of three classes. I hope that someone can help, I'll be thankful so much.

```
public class FormA: IForm 
{
    buttonClick()
    {
        Application.ActivateForm(FormB);
        var FormB = Application.Forms.GetLastForm(FormB);
        ShareFormDataEvent.Instance[FormB.UniqueID]?.Invoke(_thisForm);
    }
}

public delegate void IFormEventHandler(IForm sender);

public sealed class ShareFormDataEvent
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ShareFormDataEvent> lazy = new Lazy<ShareFormDataEvent>(() => new ShareFormDataEvent());
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IFormEventHandler> _forms;

    public static ShareFormDataEvent Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private ShareFormDataEvent()
    {
        _forms = new Dictionary<string, IFormEventHandler>();
    }

    private void SetForm(string key, IFormEventHandler value)
    {
        _forms.Add(key, value);
    }

    private IFormEventHandler GetForm(string key)
    {
        IFormEventHandler value;
        _forms.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return value;
    }

    public IFormEventHandler this[string index]
    {
        get { return GetForm(index); }
        set { SetForm(index, value); }
    }

    public IFormEventHandler CreateNewEvent(string id, object method)
    {
        IFormEventHandler a = new IFormEventHandler(form);

        return a;
    }
}
}


public class FormB: IForm 
{
    public override void OnInitialize()
    {
        base.OnInitializeComponent();
        ShareFormDataEvent.Instance.ShareData += new IFormEventHandler(ReceivingFormData); //Handler
        ShareFormDataEvent.Instance[_thisForm.UniqueID] = ShareFormDataEvent.Instance.ShareData;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

> This is an `SAP B1 Development`, that's why I'm taking this approach
>   because the Framework is too sealed for passing data from one form to
>   another.

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: I'm just guessing of what you want to achieve by doing this and I guess it is to pass a value or any kind of information to a newly created form. B1 SDK can't handle this kind of information passing so what I now days is create a datasource field and parse all the information as JSON or XML or any other serialized format as string on said text. Most of the time though I just need to pass some unique ID or some DocEntry and UserDataSources are the most concrete way to go.

Comment: @VyronPaschalidis Thanks for the info, that's was I was trying to do. For now this solution works for me, so I'll keep working with this while I do some research on what you say. I'm newbie in SAPbo so I don't have some things clear yet..cheers!

Comment: Just lookup on the SDK Help, user data sources. i believe you will find something really useful for all kinds of objectification of your forms

Answer (score 0):

I figure out some approach:

I created another class for the declaration of the event and the delegate. So, when the FormB is initialize, I'll create a new instance of this new class an store it in the dictionary of the ShareFormDataEvent class.

I think that this allow me in the future, add more events that can be(or not) used by a form, depending of the case or the goal of a form.

here's my code.

```
public class ShareDataEvent 
{
  public delegate void IFormEventHandler(IForm sender);
  public IFormEventHandler ShareData [get; set;}

}

public class FormB : IForm 
{
  public override void OnInitialize()
  {
    base.OnInitializeComponent();
    var shareDateEvent = new ShareDataEvent();
    ShareFormDataEvent.Instance[_thisForm.UniqueID] = 
    shareDataEvent; // First I add my new instance of ShareDataEvent class to the dictionary
    ShareFormDataEvent.Instance[ShareDataEvent].ShareData += new IFormEventHandler(ReceivingFormData); // Then I acces to that instance and attach the handler to the event.

  }
}
```

Hope it's help. And if are a better approach I'm open to...Cheers!